# spring converter not found after adding dependency

Tags: java, spring

I have an existing spring (5.3.9) converter. It is a state-less converter: no members, empty default constructor. With this form, it gets picked up and works well with my system:

```
class Conv implements Converter<A, B> {
    public B convert(A a) {
    ...
    }
}
```

When adding a state to this converter (any reference to another bean):

```
class Conv implements Converter<A, B> {
    // the state
    private final X x; 

    public Conv(X x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public B convert(A a) {
    ...
    }
}
```

... **The Problem**: now, the converter **cannot be found at runtime**:

> No converter found capable of converting from type [A] to type [B]

The converter itself gets to be created successfully and is still picked up by the lifecycle. The dependency gets to be injected well and it exists (stood in debug inside the constructor). There aren't any exceptions in the bean initialization process.
I have tried using construction injection; `@Autowired` injection - I am getting the same behavior.

Finally, after discussing with a colleague, he suggested adding `@Lazy` to the constructor's argument:

```
class Conv implements Converter<A, B> {
        // the state
        private final X x; 
    
        public Conv(@Lazy X x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
        public B convert(A a) {
        ...
        }
    }
```

Amazingly, it solved the problem! the converter can now be found and used as was before adding the state.

(**update**: I wasn't able to create a minimal example that reproduces this problem. it is probably related somehow to my real beans dependencies..).

Can you explain why `@Lazy` did the trick?

Comment: How do you tell Spring about your custom converter?

Comment: @aviad cohen, this is not reproduceable. Please share all the relevant code with the custom configurations that you have in order to be able to understand why it happens

Comment: @sp00m I used regular '@Component' on top of the converter class. The class is picked by the component scan and is created as part of the context initialization bootstrap phase.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos is a regular spring boot app. no special configuration file or any beans tweaking is done. I will try to create minimal standalone reproduction for this phenomenon and will post it later on.

Comment: @aviadcohen what is exactly the error then? If the bean did not have the dependency it would have failed during context initialization and the application would fail. Do you have the error stacktrace?

Comment: The problem is that after adding state the converter cannot be found at runtime, and fails on the error I listed above (edited the original post and stressed the problem for clarity). There is no exception. there is no problem loading the converter bean, except that now it is unknown to the conversion service and cannot be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that a `Converter` needs to be registered at a certain time in the lifecycle. Adding a dependency to it has changed the point at which this converter can be created.

Now when adding `@Lazy` the construction can be done at the right time again as the dependency will now only be used/detected when the dependency is used. The `@Lazy` will make a proxy of the dependency and when used will at that point do an `ApplicationContext.getBean` call instead of when constructing the object.

So basically it has to do with where in the lifecycle of the context the object can be constructed if it can be used or not.

Comment: so putting the @Lazy actually "restored" the "original order" of the construction of the beans, in which my converter was able to register successfully to the conversion service?

Comment: Yes. As the actual construction can now be delayed (for the dependency).